# Why is function not printing anything to console when called?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input

When I call the `vote()`function, the compiler doesn't print an output. Why isn't the function printing anything to the console when I call it?

Here is my code:

```
def vote(vote_one, vote_two, vote_three):
    if (vote_one == vote_two):
        return True
    elif (vote_one == vote_three):
        return True
    elif (vote_two == vote_three):
        return True
    else:
        return False

vote(1, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Is the indentation really that way? If it is your function has no body

Comment: Looks good except the indentation is bad, what error msg you get ?

Comment: I forgot to indent it. That wasn't intentional. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The error message is "Your program produced no output"

Comment: Your question says "no input", that error says "no output".

Comment: What gives that error message? The program works but it has no output. Python doesn't give an error in that case

Comment: @DarienSpringer try `print(vote(1, 2, 1))` ?

Comment: try `print(vote(1, 2, 1))`

Comment: Works well, check here https://repl.it/E6nr

Comment: It works fine, the second condition is true and so returns true

Comment: You can simplify it to `return vote_one == vote_two or vote_one == vote_three or vote_two == vote_three`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you aren't actually outputting anything. When you call vote(), a result is returned (True or False), but you aren't actually **using** the result. You could do

```
result = vote(1, 2, 1)
print(result)
```

or

```
print(vote(1, 2, 1))
```